# Push TabBarController to a View

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, tabbarcontroller

How can i push a TabBarController to a View?

The App is View-Based. In the App I have a XIB with a TabBarController and I want to push the TabBar to the display. I have done everything, and now I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code that should push the TabBarController:

```
- (void)showTabBar {
TabBar *tbc = [[TabBar alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBar" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:tbc animated:YES];
[tbc release];
}
```

At this moment there is an empty view in the XIB. So the display is white when I run this code. There is also the TabBarController, which I want to see on the display.

Thanks for your help.

---

**UPDATE:**

I should say that these are two different classes. The class where the function "showTabBar" is based should push the TabBarController. The second class is TabBar. TabBar is the delegate of the TabBarController.

So I have modified the answer like this, but I have tried both:

```
[self presentModalViewController:tbc.tabBarController.view animated:YES];
```

The error now looks like this:

```
Incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UIView *', expected 'struct UIViewController *' when passing argument 1 of 'presentModalViewController:animated:' from distinct Objective-C type
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Hey the error has gone away. Cool. ;)

But the app is terminating. I've seen this behavior before, but I didn't know what to do.
The debugger console says this:

```
2011-01-27 15:49:32.629 Touch[3657:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <StartUp: 0x9300f20>.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that is accessible through the view property. **When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

What this mean is, this is not "allowed" and Apple can or may in the future reject your application. UITabBarController is intended to be added to the root view(window) in your application delegate. If you want a tabbar to be pushed on later you need to use the UIToolBar with e.g. uisegmentedcontrol or the toolbar buttons.

Even though some apps does this(e.g Wordpress app) you will later find out that you will run onto some issues in the console when presenting viewcontrollers modally.(A warning will be given).

Comment: Ok, does this mean that I have to build the TabBar on my own without the TabBarController?

Comment: As far I know, yes. I did the same "mistake" with one app I made, because the compiler won't tell you that pushing a UITabBarController is wrong so I thought this was OK until I got help and read the documentation(it lead to other problems to because of the implicit relationship iOS sets up for you with parentViewController, tabBarController, navigationController). What I did was to make a UIToolBar, and added a UISegmentedControl which I centered. However I could have used the UIToolBarItem as-well which will give you almost the same effect. However the logic of pushing/popping views is lost.

Comment: Would you use then a normal View to fill it with all the TabBar stuff you need to build the TabBar?

Comment: Yes you would make a new viewcontroller, inheriting from the UIViewController and add components to this view.

Comment: Is it the same with all kind of controllers? Perhaps with the NavigationController or the ViewController? Do I have to build them all from scratch if I want to use them?

Comment: No, you do not need to make you own UINavigationController, this can be used "everywhere". Just remember(as far I know, I may take wrong)...UITabBar can contain UINavigationControllers, but UINavigationController can not contain UITabBarController since this must be installed as root.